# What is the amortized cost of pulling top K elements from a priority queue?

Tags: time-complexity, amortized-analysis, priority-queues

To pop an element off of a priority queue, the worst-case complexity is:

```
O(logN) where N is the number of elements.
```

Now if you do K pop operations on the priority queue, the number of elements decreases.

So the cost of these K operations would be:

```
O(logN) + O(log(N-1)) + O(log(N-2)) + O(log(N-3))... O(log(N-K))
```

How do you add these terms up? if K was a fixed number you could just amortize all of these terms to O(logN) and add them up together, so the sum becomes O(KlogN). But K is not a constant, it depends on the input!

If I wanted to pick top 5 elements from a 1000 elements, K = 5 & N = 1000. If I wanted to pick 10 elements, K would be 10.

How do you derive the cost of performing K pop operations on a priority queue?

Edit: I meant a priority queue implemented that is implemented using a heap

Comment: Note that trivially, O(log(N)) + O(log(N-1)) + O(log(N-2)) + O(log(N-3))... O(log(N-K)) ⊆ O(log(N)) + O(log(N)) + ... + O(log(N)) = O(K log(N). It turns out that the other direction is true too, so this is an equality and not just a set inclusion. The intuitive reason is that log is a very slow function which flattens everything. For most values of i, log(N-i) is very close to log(N).

Comment: Hey I think you are looking for tighter bound than O(nlogn) for removing n elements from priority queue of n elements. It doesn't exist. Try using summation n/2*h + n/4(h-1) + n/8(h-2) + .... where h is height of the tree last level n/2 elements take n/2*h operations then n/4 elements take n/4*(h-1) operation and so on... Sum it you get of the order of O(nh) which is O(nlogn).

Answer (score 5):

Big-O doesn't care about a factor 0.5, for example. Now log sqrt(N) = 1/2 log N. So if you take away enough elements to change the size of the queue from N to sqrt(N), you have multiplied the time by 0.5, which doesn't affect O(N). And there are now only sqrt(N) elements remaining, removing them even if you could do it at zero cost won't change the time complexity either.

Comment: The way your answer is currently phrased, it sounds as if you're only giving an example: "if `N-K = sqrt(N)`, then...". However, you've actually proven that no matter the value of k, the big-O of the sum will not change, because most of the `log(N-i)` terms in the sum are very close to log(N). It would be worth rephrasing your answer to make it clear it's a general proof and not just an example in the particular case K = N - sqrt(N).

Comment: What if K = N? Surely the O(KlogN) bound will still hold, but I am assuming there would be a tighter bound than O(KlogN)?